# SQL Server Query - Need to add the previous row value with the current column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I need the data in the Running_Qty field. I have pre-filled it for reference. But I need query to populate it.Initial value is 100. So 100 - Quantity = 90 and so on as in the image.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*,
       (100 - sum(quantity) over (order by id)) as running_qty
from t;
```

Cumulative sums require SQL Server 2012+.  In earlier versions, use `apply`:

```
select t.*, (100 - sum_quantity)
from t cross apply
     (select sum(t2.quantity) as sum_quantity
      from t t2
      where t2.id <= t.id
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(10),
(20),
(30),
(40),
(50),
(60);

SELECT  T.*, 100-
        ( SELECT    SUM(Quantity)
          FROM      T TT
          WHERE     TT.Quantity <= T.Quantity
        ) AS Results
FROM    T;
```